# Analogue in TikZ for the command \psshadowbox of PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

In PSTricks, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{pstcol}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-grad}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\psshadowbox[linecolor=Green,framearc=0.5,linewidth=0.3pt,fillstyle=gradient,
gradbegin=ForestGreen, gradend=GreenYellow,framesep=5pt,
shadowcolor=SpringGreen,
gradmidpoint=1]%{$\mathcal{P}_{113}$}\\[2.9cm]
{\huge{\textbf{P 113}}}\\
\psshadowbox[linecolor=Green,framearc=0.5,linewidth=0.3pt,fillstyle=gradient,
gradbegin=ForestGreen, gradend=GreenYellow,framesep=5pt,
shadowcolor=SpringGreen,
gradmidpoint=1]%{$\mathcal{P}_{113}$}\\[2.9cm]
{\Large{\textbf{P 113}}}\\

\end{document}
```

generates the following figure (300% zoom):

[image]

Is there any way to make the same figure with TikZ? I found a template with which I could do something similar, but with fixed width:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[#3] {\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}%
      #4
    \end{minipage}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\pbox{0.21 \textwidth}{}{rectangle,drop shadow, fill=Red,rounded corners=5pt,inner sep=6pt, 
shade,top color=ForestGreen, bottom color=GreenYellow, draw=Green}
{\centering{\Huge{\textbf{P 113}}}}
\pbox{0.13 \textwidth}{}{rectangle,drop shadow, fill=Red,rounded corners=5pt,inner sep=6pt,
             shade,top color=ForestGreen, bottom color=GreenYellow, draw=Green}
             {\centering{\Large{\textbf{P 113}}}}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is that the width of the box to automatically adapt the text (as with `\psshadowbox`) without having to vary the fraction `\textwidth` individually. On the other hand, I would change the color of the shadow made with TikZ to be the most similar to done with PSTricks block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the width of a TikZ `\node` is the natural width of its contents plus some `inner sep` padding on both sides, so basically all you had to do was to get rid of the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{topColor}{RGB}{0,250,0}
\definecolor{botColor}{RGB}{170,255,46}
\definecolor{shaColor}{RGB}{180,234,90}

\tikzset{
mybox/.style={
  rectangle,
  drop shadow, 
  rounded corners=5pt,
  inner sep=6pt,
  draw=topColor,
  shade,
  top color=topColor, 
  every shadow/.append style={fill=shaColor}, 
  bottom color=botColor, 
  draw=Green
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mybox]
  {\Huge\textbf{P 113}};
\node[mybox] at (0,2)
  {Some other longer test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, defining a command:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{topColor}{RGB}{0,250,0}
\definecolor{botColor}{RGB}{170,255,46}
\definecolor{shaColor}{RGB}{180,234,90}

\tikzset{
mybox/.style={
  rectangle,
  drop shadow, 
  rounded corners=5pt,
  inner sep=6pt,
  draw=topColor,
  shade,
  top color=topColor,
  every shadow/.append style={fill=shaColor}, 
  bottom color=botColor, 
  draw=Green
  }
}

\newcommand\MyBox[2][]{%
  \tikz\node[mybox,#1] {#2}; 
}

\begin{document}

\MyBox{\Huge\textbf{P 113}}\par\medskip
\MyBox{Some other longer test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\Huge` is *not* a command with arguments; it's a font switch to be used as in  `{\Huge <text>}` or `{\Huge <text>\par}`, if required.